# Possible to load 2 sets of aws credentials from Json file?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, credentials

I'm building a node.js express app and I need to be able to pull 2 sets of credentials based on the context that the user is in. I have it set so it can pull 1 set of credentials from a config file.

In my main.js file I load the SDK and the credentials for the whole app. However I'd like to be able to switch credentials based on the route, Is that possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

[This blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/a-new-and-standardized-way-to-manage-credentials-in-the-aws-sdks/) provides some helpful information on this subject. You will want to define the credentials as different profiles in your config file. Then, when you want to use a different set of credentials for a specific service you would specify the profile when initializing the service, like so:

```
var creds = new AWS.SharedIniFileCredentials({ profile: 'my_profile_name' });
var client = new AWS.EC2({ credentials: creds });
```

Comment: I think that might be only if it's locally saved on your PC. Configured through the CLI. I'm trying to load multiple credentials from a config.json file in the app itself. That way it works when it's deployed. Like so: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/loading-node-credentials-json-file.html

Comment: It entirely depends on how you have the credentials configured. This method would work fine if you have the standard config file present. It isn't only for local PCs, I use this method on production servers. It looks like you are using a JSON File for configuration, so I believe you would pass a `FileSystemCredentials` instance instead of a `SharedIniFileCredentials` instance.

Comment: Would I have to leave it as a .json file or just a regular config file? I'm new to using aws services and a lot of this is still sinking in. Thanks for the help

Comment: Look at the documentation. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/FileSystemCredentials.html `FileSystemCredentials` takes a JSON file. If you want to use an ini file then you can override the path that `SharedIniFileCredentials` will use to look for your credentials file. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SharedIniFileCredentials.html